# Best way to Select from 3 tables in my query

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables with the following terms. Please guide me to 
get the best selection process from them

- my tables:

  ```
   player :  |  id  |  status  |  credit  |  userid  |   showtime  |

   player_log :  |  srl  |  ip  |  date  | 

   player_stat :  |  srl  |  stat  |  date  |
  ```

There is a table for player details and two other tables have recorded his activities.

I'm supposed to choose a player who has not played before and his stats are not higher than I am considering.

player id saved in srl and $uid is a banned user for one day

---

- Players with these conditions **should be** in the results :

  ```
  status=11 and credit>=$20 and            
  userid NOT LIKE $uid and            
  (showtime=$hgroup or showtime=0)
  ```

---

- Players who have these conditions **should be removed** from the results :

*condition1*

```
player_log.srl=player.id and     
player_log.ip=$ip and    
player_log.date=$date
```

*condition2*

```
player_stat.srl=player.id and       
player_stat.stat>=$dailylimit and   
player_stat.date=$date
```

Comment: Hint: Use joins.

Comment: If there's a relationship between `player`, `player_log` and `player_stat` I'd expect to see `player_id` in both the `player_log` and `player_stat` tables - or *"link"* tables.

Comment: explain better what do you mean for 'userid NOT LIKE $uid'